# Easiest way to copy many conditional formats

Tags: conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

What is the easiest way to copy many conditional formats without Calc collapsing column-based formats down to a multi-range format?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.